# How to set member of a 2D array: ArrayList<Object[]>?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am stuck on a fairly simple problem. I have an arraylist of arrays. Im trying to set a member in a array inside the arraylist. However, I'm getting some errors. Can you guys check it out for me?

```
 public static ArrayList findPercentages(ArrayList<Object[]> al, int max)
 {
    ArrayList<Object[]> a = al; 
    for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++)
    {
        a.set(a.indexOf((i))[2],((Integer)al.get((i)[2])/max));
    }
    return a;

 }
```

Comment: what are the errors?  The above code is next to un-readable.  Try splitting it out.  Get the object, modify the object, update the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax would be:

```
a.get(i)[2] = a.get(i)[2] / max;
```

Every element in `a` is an `Object[]`, so `a.get(index)` returns an `Object[]`.

However, this can't really work anyways as is because division operators don't apply to `Object`. You'll have to use a more specific primitive wrapper type (e.g. `Float`) instead of `Object`.

If you *know* that all the elements in the arrays are `Float` (for example), you could cast it:

```
a.get(i)[2] = (Float)a.get(i)[2] / max;
```

But this is sloppy, cumbersome, and error prone and is a red flag indicating that you should be using more appropriate types. (Also, you should really specify a type parameter in the returned `ArrayList` type; otherwise you're going to be stuck making potentially incorrect unchecked/unsafe casts all over the place.)

By the way, the [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method is for *finding* an item in a list, not accessing an item at a specific index.